# Android (or Android compatible Java) library to draw editable flow chart diagrams

Tags: java, android, graphics, diagram, flowchart

I'm developing a flow chart drawing tool for Android and even though it has been a month I still couldn't find a good, reliable graphics library to help me develop this app.

Here are a few things I tried:

1-) Android views. Since a flowchart would naturally include lots and lots of shapes, this option wasn't satisfactory in terms of performance. Plus, I didn't even know how to draw arrows.

2-) Canvas. It was quite good when it comes to performance but canvas does nothing more than coloring pixels, so I can't go back to editing them after placing a shape on the screen.

3-) Now I'm working on Qt to see if I can achieve my goals and so far it seems as though it's very doable but using a cross-platform development software for only Android doesn't make a lot of sense.

4-) Libgdx and Unity are also options but using a game engine for such a lightweight app didn't seem like a very good idea to me.

Can you suggest me a good library or any other development tool?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is https://github.com/mocircle/cidrawing library. Maybe useful for this type of task with link to https://github.com/Team-Blox/GraphView library.

Hope it helps.